# Python reading CSV file using URL giving error

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I am trying to read a CSV file using the requests library but I am having issues.

```
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/sentiment-analysis-dataset/training_data.csv'
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.iter_lines()
reader = csv.reader(text, delimiter=',')
```

I then tried

```
for row in reader:
  print(row)
```

but it gave me this error:

```
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
text = r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True)
```

This will return a `strings`-iterator instead of a `bytes`-iterator. (See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) for documentation.)